# Craft Commerce: No Emails sent on Default Order Status

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I noticed while doing some testing that assigned emails for the default order status do not get sent. An email does get sent on every other order status change without any problems. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Solved! Wrong template names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this with a default Craft Commerce installation, assigned an email to the default "Processing" order status, placed an order and received the email as expected.

I'd double check under `Settings->Email` in the Craft control panel you're not using phpmail or sendmail and you're using a proper SMTP server or transactional email provider like [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) or [Mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com/), etc.  The others are notoriously unreliable at delivering email.  See: https://craftcms.com/support/troubleshooting-email-errors#dealing-with-email-delivery-issues

Comment: In addition, check your commerce.log file for parsing errors with the template for that statuses email...